# Localisation failing in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-webassembly

I am having difficulties adding multiple languages in Blazor WASM. I've been following various guides online, but what I am finding is that trying to change the culture during runtime will fail, unless a non-default culture was set in Program.Main().

For example, in Program.Main(), if I put the following:

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        builder.Services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
        
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
```

And correspondingly, have 2 .resx files, for example:

BlazorControl.resx

BlazorControl.es.resx

Then when BlazorControl is displayed, the strings will correctly be in Spanish. I have then put in a click event handler on that control that changes the culture to English:

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<PagingControls> Localiser
    
<h1 @onclick="OnClicked">@Localiser["Hello"]</h1>

@code {
    private void OnClicked()
    {
        var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

That works fine, great.

However, if I do not set a non-default culture in Program.Main(), for example having Program.Main() as:

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        builder.Services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
```

and the click event as:

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<PagingControls> Localiser
    
<h1 @onclick="OnClicked">@Localiser["Hello"]</h1>

@code {
    private void OnClicked()
    {
        var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Then nothing happens. The control is displayed in English on startup (correctly), but is not changed by the click event.

My interpretation is that Blazor does not load the non-default resource file at all unless it is specifically required before the application launches. My question is, how to get this working properly?

I am considering just making my own localiser with JSON files, but I would prefer to do things the Microsoft way if possible.

Note: I could just set the culture to Spanish on startup, then change it to English when it loads, but that would only be a 'solution' if there were only 2 languages on the system, whereas I plan to have more.

Comment: I have the same issue.
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-webassembly
Adding `<PropertyGroup><BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData></PropertyGroup>` to the csproj file should do the trick, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, where it seemed like all the other languages didn't load, if not selected as default.

The problem was, that I used a library like https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage to store the selected language in the browser. It seemed like a cleaner solution, than writing some JS myself and calling it using interops.

However, the problem with this is, that in order to read and write values this way, blazor must already be initialized. The localization framework doesn't seem to like this very much, so I fixed it with a little js snippet in the header of my `index.html`.

```
<script>
    if (!localStorage.getItem("appCulture")) localStorage.setItem("appCulture", navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage);
</script>
```

It simply makes sure, that there is a value present in the localStorage, by the time Program.cs executes. Previously, this happened after the execution of host.Build(), since I used C# and JS interops to achieve the same thing.